# How to add empty children array for the empty parents?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a JSON populated output.
Wherever the children are not available the children index is missing.

```
[7] => Array
(   
    [id] => 171
    [text] => Some Text
    [groupid] => 170
    [leaf] => false
    [qtip] => Cool
)
```

However, I need the children to be added with an empty array.

```
[7] => Array
(   
    [id] => 171
    [text] => Some Text
    [groupid] => 170
    [leaf] => false
    [qtip] => Cool
    [children] => []
)
```

Here is my code that creates the output:

```
$res = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();
$result = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $tmpData = false;
    foreach ($result as $k => &$val) {
        $tmpData[$val['id']] = &$val;
    }
    
    foreach ($result as $k => &$val) {
        if ($val['groupid'] && isset($tmpData[$val['groupid']])) {
            $tmpData[$val['groupid']]['children'][] = &$val;
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($result as $k => &$val) {
        if ($val['groupid'] && isset($tmpData[$val['groupid']])) {
            unset($result[$k]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A null value and an empty array are two different things

Comment: @JoePhillips, yes, I need an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res->execute();
$result = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $tmpData = false;
    foreach ($result as $k => &$val) {
        $tmpData[$val['id']] = &$val;
    }
    
    foreach ($result as $k => &$val) {
        if ($val['groupid'] && isset($tmpData[$val['groupid']])) {
            $tmpData[$val['groupid']]['children'][] = &$val;
        } else {
           $tmpData[$val['groupid']]['children'] = [];
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($result as $k => &$val) {
        if ($val['groupid'] && isset($tmpData[$val['groupid']])) {
            unset($result[$k]);
        }
    }
```

By the way the idea is "play" with exists or not the `$val`.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can u give us an example of initial `$result` ?

Comment: The part of the `$result` is in the question. I'm not sure exactly what you want to see. If there is a fiddle for PHP I will create one.